How to customize shapviz plots?
I'm a recent user of the {shapviz} package and I'm having some difficulties customizing the graphs (like the importance graph).
I would like, for example:

to change the color palette in the case of beeswarm plot and the colors in the case of the bar plot;
to change the legend (title and size) [something like theme(legend.key.size = unit(2, 'cm')];
to change the texts/labels of the numbers (show_numbers = TRUE) [as if I were using the geom_text( ), geom_label( ) or annotation( ) functions].

Since shapviz plots are of the ggplot type, I tried to change them by accessing the lists or adding layers, but I was unsuccessful.
Thanks!

Using some toy data, here's how you could change those aesthetics:
library(xgboost)
library(shapviz)
library(viridis)
library(ggplot2)

# Toy data
X_train <- data.matrix(iris[, -1])
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label = iris[, 1], nthread = 1)
fit <- xgb.train(data = dtrain, nrounds = 10, nthread = 1)
x <- shapviz(fit, X_pred = X_train)

# Modify shapviz plot
p <- sv_importance(x, kind = "both", show_numbers = TRUE, fill = "red") +
  scale_colour_gradient(
    low = "darkblue", high = "skyblue",
    breaks = c(0, 1), labels = c("low", "high")
  ) +
  labs(colour = "My Title") +
  theme(
    legend.key.size = unit(2, "cm"),
    legend.title.position = "right",
    legend.title = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0.5)
  )

# Add geom_label and remove the geom_text
p2 <- p +
  geom_label(aes(x, y, label = label), data = layer_data(p, 4), fontface = "italic")

p2$layers[[4]] <- NULL

p2


Created on 2024-04-08 with reprex v2.1.0

Thanks in advance, Carl!
But do you see that by changing the color scale in this way the legend stops being in the range from "low" to "higher" (and adopts a scale from zero to 1) and the title goes to the top (and not to the right side)?

I've added a couple of further tweaks.  Does that give you what you'd like to achieve? Looks neater on the left, but you can change that if you prefer the right.

Wow! Thanks a million! Just one more question: how to add boxes around the numbers (of show_numbers = TRUE)?

Added a geom_label and removed the existing geom_text.

Great answer. Just wanted to add that there is a fill argument that controls the bar fill color.

Thanks for the catch re the fill argument in sv_importance(). Easy to miss the obvious :)
